# React link not working after uploading the project on live server

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I made a dashboard on the React project. All the things are working fine but when I upload the project on the test server some of the links show a 404 error (https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLfKd.png).

Here is the screenshot of the link which gave a 404 error (https://i.stack.imgur.com/JI7Ob.png). When I click on the edit link, it shows a 404 error.

Here is routing of my customer component.

```
<div className="col-md-12 bg-gray" style={padding}>
                <div className="row" style={row}>
                <h3 className="paragraph mgb-30 roboto">Customers</h3>
                </div>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/dashboard/customers" exact component={CustomerTable} />
                <Route path="/dashboard/customers/list" component={CustomerTable} />
                <Route path="/dashboard/customers/add" component={AddCustomer} />
                <Route path="/dashboard/customers/update" component={UpdateCustomer} />
            </Switch>
            </div>
```

Here is the code of CustomerTable

```
 <td className="customer-action relative">
                            <i className="fa fa-ellipsis-v customer-icon"></i>
                            <span className="customer-detail-container">
           <ul className="list customer-detail-list">
           <li><Link to="/dashboard/customers/update" className="normal-link"><img src={Eye} alt="Edit customer"  style={icon} />Edit</Link></li>
           <li onClick={this.showAlert}><img src={Download} alt="Delete customer" style={icon} />Delete</li>
           </ul>
           </span>
                            
                        </td>
```

This is actually a dropdown that I made in react with jQuery. Initially, it has `display: none`. When I click on icon its display turn into a block.

Comment: Has nothing to do with react, have your webserver serve index.html when requesting non existing content.

Comment: I don't know what the issue is. But I sure that there is some problem with React routing. When I click on the link in the localhost it refreshes the page. Each link which refreshes the page in the localhost didn't work on live host.

Comment: also when I changed ul dropdown with single Link element, all things working fine in localhost as well as the live server.

Comment: Can you share the URL of the link that not working and also the Home URL of the application

Comment: `When I click on the link in the localhost it refreshes the page` Then your app is broken, react router should produce a spa (**single page** application). When you run it locally I assume you run it in dev mode with `yarn start` that starts `react-script start` so it'll use webpack dev server to serve your app and will serve index.html when you do `localhost:3000/does/not/exist`.